# replacing hourly missing value with yearly average of that hour of the day 

Tags: r

I have a hourly dataset from 1996 - 2010 in the following format:

```
             date         value  
1- - -1996-01-01 00:00:00- - -  NA  
2- - -1996-01-01 01:00:00- - -  38  
3 - - -1996-01-01 02:00:00- - - 44  
4- - -1996-01-01 03:00:00- - -  48  
5- - -1996-01-01 04:00:00- - -  42  
6- - -1996-01-01 05:00:00- - -  44  
7- - - 1996-01-01 06:00:00- - - 38  
8- - - 1996-01-01 07:00:00- - - 42  
9- - -1996-01-01 08:00:00- - -  44  
10- - -1996-01-01 09:00:00- - - 44
```

I have lot of missing hours data and I am tring to calculate the missing hour values by taking the average of previous and next hour, and if many hours missing I am trying to calculate by taking the average of that hour for every day that year, just wondering if this is possible?

I have tried the following but this gives me average of the complete dataset:

```
a = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 10)   
a[which(is.na(a)==TRUE)] = mean(a,na.rm = T)
```

I would really appreciate any advice about how I should proceed with this calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this using some handy function from the **zoo** package. For instance, `na.approx`, with `maxgap = 1` should linearly interpolate all the gaps of length one. Then you'd probably want to use `na.aggregate`, splitting by year and hour, to fill longer gaps with that periods' mean.

Here's a simple example to give you a sense of how these functions work:

```
set.seed(124)
tt <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 10:00:00") + 3600*c(1:100,10000:10100)
dd <- runif(201)

aa <- data.frame(x1 = tt,x2 = dd)
aa$x2[sample(201,30)] <- NA
aa$x3 <- na.approx(aa$x2,maxgap = 1)
aa$x4 <- na.aggregate(aa$x3,by = format(aa$x1,"%Y-%H"))
```

Note that if your series has leading or trailing `NA`s, you might get errors, since the "linear interpolation" piece doesn't make much sense in that case. So you'd have to fill those in some other way.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I will try this monday and will let you know how it goes! Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

`na.aggregate` in zoo does that.  Its only one line of code to fill in the missing values:

```
# read in the data

Lines <- "1996-01-01 00:00:00 NA  
1996-01-01 01:00:00 38  
1996-01-01 02:00:00 43
1997-01-01 00:00:00 44  
1997-01-01 01:00:00 45"

library(zoo)
library(chron)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:2, FUN = paste, FUN2 = as.chron)

# fill in the missing values

na.aggregate(z, hours, FUN = mean)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply too, I will try this monday and will let you know how it went, thanks